# RegFree DLL with CPython using win32com module

Tags: python, dll, regfreecom, win32com

I am currently using the win32com module of CPython to use a DLL.
I know some people using IronPython to automagically get the list of functions provided by this DLL. They don't need to register the DLL.

I'd like to do the same as them but with CPython.

1) Is it possible to use CPython and win32com to connect to a dll reg-free. How to make it reg-free?

2) How to get the list of functions provided by the DLL? I'd like to create a CPython module providing the whole list of functions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of information is *hard*, very very hard to find information about.  I am attempting to find the same but for Ruby, however I expect that the same issue will occur.  Ultimately, however, a Manifest file is required, and at least during development, it may help to register the .dll anyway, and then work on making it registration free (with a manifest file)